# usage of JSON API links section

Tags: json-api

A project I'm working on has decided to use [JSON API](http://jsonapi.org/) as a standard for all API endpoints. However I'm not sure that the spec is being followed correctly regarding the top-level "links".

An example response from our API might be:

```json
{
  "data": {
    "type": "submarine",
    "id": "yellow",
    "links": {
      "sailor": "https://example.com/sailors",
      "stowaway": "https://example.com/stowaways",
      "surface": "https://example.com/submarines/yellow/surface",
      "crew": "https://example.com/submarines/yellow/crew"
    },
    "attributes": {
      "is_submerged": true
    },
    "relationships": {
      "crew": {
        "data": [
          {"type": "sailor", "id": "john"},
          {"type": "sailor", "id": "paul"},
          {"type": "sailor", "id": "george"},
          {"type": "sailor", "id": "ringo"}
        ]
      },
      "stowaways": {
        "data": [
          {"type": "stowaway", "id": "bootleg-beatles"}
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

- `POST`ing to the "surface" link would cause the submarine to invoke its various procedures required to rise to the surface;
- `GET`ting the "crew" link would return a list of the crew members assigned to the submarine with full details (attributes/relationships/etc.);
- The "sailor" / "stowaway" links would be used if a new subresource is required. For example, if a stowaway is discovered on the submarine, their attributes would be `POST`ed to the "stowaway" link, along with the current submarine ID. They would then appear in the relationships for the submarine in later requests.

To me, each of these uses seems to go against the spirit of discoverability, but I can't say with certainty how these actions and links *should* be surfaced; each time I suggest an alternative, further reading of the spec seems to suggest that my suggestion also doesn't conform correctly.

Unfortunately the wording of the spec is rather unclear, simply stating that:

> The top-level links object **MAY** contain the following members:
>
> - self: the link that generated the current response document.
> - related: a related resource link when the primary data represents a resource relationship.
> - pagination links for the primary data.

http://jsonapi.org/format/#document-top-level

---

So my question is which of these three use cases (if any) actually belong in the "links" section? For those which don't belong there, how *should* we be doing it instead?

Comment: Top level links would be at same level as data member.  Your example has resource level links.

Comment: @BF4 Thank you; that clarifies which bit of the document I should be looking at. It mentions "self" and "related", and "Note: Additional members may be specified for links objects and link objects in the future.". Would I be correct in interpreting that to mean that it can **only** have "self" and "related", and any custom links don't belong there?